# Calculating an average based on specific time increments

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

In column C I have a set values in 15 minute increments. I want to get an average of column C in different time increments. For example, if I wanted a 15 minute average, I need it to average C1:C2, then C2:C3, then C3:C4 and so on. If in was for 60 minutes, I need it to average C1:C4, then C2:C5, then C3:C6 and so on.

I have been having a lot of trouble trying to figure this out... Can anybody help me? Thank you!

Comment: If the averages in question are distinct vales e.g. C1:C4 being one value then C2:C5 being another, you can create AVERAGE formula in adjacent columns and drag the formula down the column, it will take the next similar range increment.

Comment: Please provide an example in your question to help us better understand

Answer (score 1):

If you create a table, you can use `Indirect()` and `Vlookup()`:

[image]

`=AVERAGE(INDIRECT("C"&VLOOKUP($A$1,$G$1:$I$4,2)&":C"&VLOOKUP($A$1,$G$1:$I$4,3)))`

In $A$1, you can put the time frame you want to get.  Column C is your values you want averaged.  The Vlookup table is pretty straightforward.  Just combine `Indirect` with the vlookup, and your range will change as you change $A$1.